# Django Model Field default value not applied when creating object manually

Tags: python, django

Say my object has a `DecimalField` with default set to `20`. When I create an object in python and don't specify a value for that `DecimalField`, it's `None`.

How to make sure that default value is applied every time I don't supply a value?

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    """Demonstrate the flaw of the default value."""

    dec_field = models.DecimalField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)


my_model = SomeModel()
my_model.save()  # this is where I expect the dec_field to become Decimal('1.0')
                 # instead it's None
```

Comment: add the code where you are setting the default value

Comment: can you share the code?  decimal = models.DecimalField(default=20)

Comment: and also add the code of the form , from which you are submitting this decimal value to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your model and database are synchronized, either with a migration tool such as South, or by dropping the table and resyncing.

Answer (score 1):

The default should be set with what you have described, would need more info about your example. But if you wanted to override, or set the default manually you could do the following;

```
DEC_FIELD_DEFAULT = 20
class Example(models.Model):
    dec_field = models.DecimalField(default=DEC_FIELD_DEFAULT)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.dec_field = DEC_FIELD_DEFAULT
```

Comment: I like what you do in the __init__, but this is what I expect Django to do by default. Kind of not true DRY if I have to do it myself.